# cx_freeze - unable to import openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl, cx-freeze

I am using cx_freeze to create a .exe file which accesses the openpyxl module. However when the application tries to import openpyxl it crashes, telling: "Python stopped working"

It seems to be some kind of bug with cx_freeze, so far I haven't found any solution on google and therefor chose to ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution, the team who developed cx_freeze has acknowledged the problem. But can't find any good solution to the problem, and therefor chose to not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an answer ! Based on thefromanguard's answer [1], if you install previous version of openpyxl (2.3.5) the executable works (worked for me)

[1] : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39396636/10185825